# Find the entire function $f(z)$ such that $\vert f(z) \vert \leq \vert z \vert \ln(\vert z \vert +1)$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

$Q)$ The entire function, $f(z) : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ $s.t.$ $\vert f(z) \vert \leq \vert z \vert  \ln(\vert z \vert +1)$ for $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}.$ Find the $f(z)$ satisfying the  $f(1) = i$

From now, My solution starts.

Since the $f$ is entire, $f(z) = a_0 + a_1z + ...  +a_nz^n+...$

There are some fixed $a_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ plus, By Cauchy integral formula, $a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\vert z \vert = r} \frac{f(z)}{z^{n+1}}dz$

From the above I could derive conclusion the $\vert a_n\vert \leq \frac{\ln(r+1)}{r^{n-1}}$ for the $\vert z \vert =r$

It is clear for the $n>1$ with the $r\to\infty$, $\vert a_n \vert =0$ (I.e. $a_n = 0$)

But the problem is the case $n=1$

I considered the case the  $r \to 0$ with the  $\vert a_1 \vert \leq ln(r+1)$. Hence I got the $\vert a_1 \vert = 0 $(I.e. $a_1 = 0$)

So my answer is $f(z) =i$ on $\mathbb {C}$

But that answer is false because $f(0) \neq 0$. I'm trying to find the which point did I make mistake, But still can't find it. What did I wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you've done anything wrong; I think no such function exists!

The inequality $|f(z)| \le |z|\ln(|z|+1)$ implies that $f(z)$ has a double zero at $z=0$ (in other words, that $a_0=a_1=0$, as you noted a different way). But you've also correctly shown that $a_n=0$ for $n\ge2$. Therefore the only entire function satisfying $|f(z)| \le |z|\ln(|z|+1)$ is $f(z)=0$.

Perhaps the writer of the question meant to assume only that $|f(z)| \le |z|\ln(|z|+1)$ for $|z|\ge2$ or something like that, in which case the answer would be $f(z)=iz$.